# command line parsing in bash translated to powershell

Tags: bash, powershell

I dont know bash all that well but I inherited a script I need to translate to powershell. How to go about it?

```
# parse command line arguments
while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; do
    key="$1"

    case $key in  
        # one of: "one", "two", "three", "four"
        -s|--system)
            system="$2"
            shift # past argument
            shift # past value
            ;;
        *)  # unknown option
            shift # past argument
            ;;
    esac
done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to take a look at PowerShell's [Advanced Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-7).

You won't have to handle the case of unknown parameters because using one will cause an error.

For restricting parameter values or validating input, you'll want to check out the [parameter attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-7#parameter-attribute) section. This goes over concepts like parameter sets (mutually exclusive parameters), whether you can accept a parameter value from the pipeline, how to make a parameter mandatory, etc. You can get pretty advanced with it, or keep it simple, but it does greatly reduce parameter parsing code when compared to other runtimes.

---

To keep it simple though, here is how you would define the above code using Advanced Parameters as it is written above:

```
Param(
  [string]$System
)
```

This will create the `System` parameter with type `String` and would be invoked as such:

```
Function-OrScript -System server01
```

If you want multiple parameters, just separate each parameter with a comma `,`:

```
Param(
  [string]$Server,
  [string]$Build
)
```

---

You could extend this to take multiple systems in one parameter too by making the type a string array, if desired:

```
Param(
  [string[]]$System
)
```

Which would be invoked as such (you can also just include a single value and it will still work):

```
Function-OrScript -System server01, server02, server0X
```

Comment: How do I do the looping/case logic?

Comment: You don't need to loop like you have to with `getopts` to parse out the arguments with PowerShell.

Comment: No not how to use loops. So my understanding is that if I give the command line  parse.ps1 --build one --server two  the $System param will hold the array {build=one,server=two}?

Comment: No, in your example you only have a single parameter to be processed, `-system`. If you want two parameters you'll have to define two.

Comment: The `while` loop in your `bash` script is parsing arguments and setting variables. You don't have to do this when parsing paremeters in PowerShell. If you want `-System` to be specified multiple times, use the `[string[]` example I provided in my answer to accept multiple `-System` values. Eventually in your code, yes, you may have to loop over each element in `$System` to perform whatever operation you need for each `$System`.